# Elixir/golang и html вопросик

Tags: elixir

всем привет. что с сайтами на голанг или эликсир? вот есть 2 файла - хтмл основной и потом второй языка программирования. в случае с джаваскрипт 
так вот делают путь. а в случае с голангом или элексиром? как быть? что писать?
подскажите, пожалуйста, я нуб...

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: У сайта есть две части: фронтэнд и бэкэнд. Фронтэнд обычно - html+css+js (вместо голого js может быть какой-нибудь язык, транслируемый в js, например typescript или kotlin). А бэкэнд вообще на любом языке фактически может быть - хоть golang, хоть elixir, хоть с++ или ассемблер. Обычно - что-нибудь из списка js, python, ruby, java, php.

Comment: Также фронтэнд может быть реализован на webassembly, тогда там может использоваться какой-то компилируемый язык, например c++ или rust. Но это отдельная большая тема.